# Mongodb error [pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError] in flask web-service

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, flask, docker-compose

So i made a flask web-service that connects to a mongodb , the web-service will be in a docker container and the mongodb will be in another container. When i run the web-service locally on my computer it connects to the mongodb container and everything works fine. When i have them in 2 separated containers as described before, i can use GET methods just fine but POST methods never works, every time i try to make a change in the db or insert something the programm just freezes for some seconds and then i get the timeout error [image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy2Zi.png). One of the endpoints of the web-service that has a problem is this (i will also add the beginning of the file so you can see the connection with the db ):

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import date

client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")

db=client["DigitalNotes"]
users=db["Users"]
admins=db["Admins"]
notes=db["Notes"]

app=Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/sign_up",methods=["POST"])
def sign_up():
    try:
        data=json.loads(request.data)
    except Exception as e:
        return Response("Bad json content",status=500,mimetype='application/json')
    if data==None:
        return Response("Bad request",status=500,mimetype='application/json')
    if not "email" in data or not "username" in data or not "name" in data or not "password" in data:
        return Response("Information incompleted",status=500,mimetype='application/json')
    
    if users.count_documents({"email":data["email"]})==0 or users.count_documents({"username":data["username"]})==0:
        user = {"email":data["email"],"username":data["username"],"name":data["name"],"password":data["password"]}
        users.insert_one(user)
        return Response(data["username"]+" was added to the DataBase",status=200,mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        return Response("A user with the given username or password already exists",status=200,mimetype='application/json')
```

and the Dockerfile that creates the container is this:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install flask pymongo
RUN pip3 install datetime
RUN mkdir /app
COPY app.py /app/app.py
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python3","-u","app.py"]
```

The container of the mongodb is created in an docker-compose file which is this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
    - 27017:27027
    volumes:
    - ./mongodb/data:/data/db
  flask-service:
    build:
      context: ./flask-service
    restart: always
    container_name: flask
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      - "MONGO_HOSTNAME=mongodb"
```

I just don't understand why it works fine locally and not in the containers. Can anyone please help??

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string of MongoDb in flask container should be `mongodb://mongodb:27017` because between containers you should specify the service name.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I have been struggling for days!